# Pointer to element of std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, function-object

I have something like

```
struct functor
{
  functor(){}
  virtual int operator()()=0;
};

struct impl : public functor
{
  int i;
  impl(int ii) : i(ii) {}
  virtual int operator()(){return i;};
};

void call(functor& f) {std::cout << f() << std::endl;}
class holder
{
public:
  holder(){}
  std::vector<functor*> dps;
};

class veer
{
public:
  std::vector<holder> hs;
  std::vector<impl> ds;
  veer(){}
  void add_h(int i)
  {
    ds.push_back(impl(i));
    holder th;
    th.dps.push_back(&ds.back()); //here
    hs.push_back(th);
  }
};
int main()
{
  veer v;
  v.add_h(10);
  v.add_h(9);
  for (auto ih: v.hs)   
    for (auto ifn : ih.dps)
    call(*ifn);
  return 0;
}
```

This seg faults. I'm sorry I can't make it any simpler, this is simplest and closest to my actual code as I could make it. I need the vector of pointers to function objects. My guess is that the line marked `//here` I'm sending an invalid pointer, but other than that, I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: You have a potential problem here because you do not provide a virtual destructor in `functor`. If you were to do a polymorphic deletion of an `impl` through a `functor` pointer, it would be undefined behavior. I don't see that you're doing that in this code, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that `vector` [is not guaranteed to keep the same storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
>   references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Each time you call `add_h`, you're potentially invalidating all the pointers you have stored in your `std::vector<functor*>`. I can't think of a use case to have a vector of things and a vector of pointers to those things in the same order.. are you sure this is what you need?

`std::vector` tends to use something on the order of the space it needs, so sometimes it needs to expand its storage. Under the hood, it has to create a new array, copy the existing elements over, and delete the old one. When it does that, all your old pointers are now pointing at `delete`ed memory.

Comment: Worse, the code tries to hold on to the pointer of a local (temporary, actually) object.

Comment: Right, I'm treating these like old C arrays. That makes a lot of sense. I'm stupidly assuming it has a fixed length and hasn't reallocated memory. I probably should try to figure out a better way instead of this non-sense.

Comment: @KonradRudolph does `&vec.back()` not give you the pointer to the actual vector since it returns a reference? Or is there something else I'm not noticing?

Comment: @Collin `ds.back()` isn’t the issue, `ds.push_back(impl(i));` is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph veer::ds is a vector of impl's stored by value. holder::ds (now holder::dps) is a vector of functor pointers (superclass of impl). I attempted to get the address to the element of veer::ds, which I assume was passed by value into the veer::ds vector. Is this incorrect?
Yeah, I understand how that the naming is unfortunate, I can change that.

Comment: @noobermin Oh I see, `ds` is in the same scope as `hs`. Not a bug then, but still very unclear ownership here, this is certainly screaming for somebody to make a mistake in the future. Maybe proper naming would help but since dangling references are easily the #1 source of segfaults in modern C++ I would invest some thought into making this type safe (so that a dangling reference would somehow trigger a type error – without having thought about this, I cannot say how to approach this though).